# How to sort query by connections number

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

`Parent` and `Child` tables are linked with `parent_uuid` ForeignKey attribute:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import uuid

Base = declarative_base()
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    uuid = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    def __init__(self):  
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()   

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    uuid = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    parent_uuid = Column(String(64), ForeignKey('parents.uuid'))
    def __init__(self, parent_uuid=None):  
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()   
        self.parent_uuid = parent_uuid
```

`for` loop is used to declare `Parent` objects. And with `random.randomint()`) each `parent` is linked random number of children:

```
for i in range(25):
    parent = Parent()
    session.add(parent)
    session.commit()
    parent_uuid = parent.uuid 
    for i in range(random.randint(0, 10)):
        child = Child(parent_uuid=parent_uuid)
        session.add(child)
        session.commit()
```

How to query all `Parent` entities ordering them by a number of linked `Children`. `Parent` with the highest number of `children` should be the first in a list. I could be sorting by `uuid` attribute using `order_by()` function:

```
session.query(Parent).order_by(desc(Parent.uuid)).all()
```

But here, the number of children needs to be calculated first. How to sort by a value that was not yet calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partition by, with a count function which will add the count of each of the children related to their parents. Then you can use that column to order by.

Looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import desc, func

query = session.query(Parent, Child, func.count().over(partition_by=Parent.uuid)
.label('children_count'))
.filter(Child.parent_uuid == Parent.uuid)
.order_by(desc('children_count'))
print(query)
```

which will produce the following sql:

```
SELECT parents.uuid AS parents_uuid, children.uuid AS children_uuid,
children.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, 
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parents.uuid) AS children_count
FROM parents, children
WHERE children.parent_uuid = parents.uuid ORDER BY children_count DESC
```

which gives you parents and children sorted by the highest count of related children records.

Comment: Didn't realise MySQL doesn't support analytical functions.  You may have to write this using raw sql : see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22391496/110772.  Good luck!

Comment: Or, *if possible*, switch to postgres?

Comment: `MySql` raises ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY parents.uuid) AS anon_1 \nFROM parents, children' at line 1") [SQL: u'SELECT parents.uuid AS parents_uuid, children.uuid AS children_uuid, children.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parents.uuid) AS anon_1 \nFROM parents, children']