# mysql -- ERROR 1064 (42000): .... near '(PARTITION BY t1.DIGEST)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I tried to execute this query in ubuntu / mysql:

```
SELECT t1.SCHEMA_NAME, CONCAT(ROUND(BUCKET_QUANTILE*100,2),"% under ",
               BUCKET_TIMER_HIGH/1000000000," milliseconds") fact, 
               LEFT(QUERY_SAMPLE_TEXT,64) as QUERY_SAMPLE, t1.DIGEST, 
               COUNT(t1.DIGEST) 
               OVER(PARTITION BY t1.DIGEST) as TOT 
              FROM events_statements_histogram_by_digest t1 
              JOIN events_statements_summary_by_digest t2 
                ON t2.DIGEST = t1.DIGEST 
             WHERE COUNT_BUCKET >1 
             ORDER BY t1.DIGEST, BUCKET_TIMER_HIGH DESC 
             LIMIT 10\G
```

and the result :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'(PARTITION BY t1.DIGEST) as TOT FROM events_statements_histogram_by_digest t1 JO' 
at line 1
```

I have not found a way to correct that query. Please help. thanks.

Comment: Unless you are using MySQL 8 it doesn't support `OVER(PARTITION BY...`

Comment: @Nick -- what is the "PARTITION BY" in mysql5 +?

Comment: There isn't really an equivalent in MySQL 5.x. You might be able to emulate it with `GROUP BY`. I'm only just starting to use MySQL 8 so not familiar enough with `PARTITION` to be able to offer a solution sorry.

Comment: Without knowing what your result should look like it is hard to suggest an alternative. While the usual way to simulate a partition function is a variable, in your case it looks like you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22391452/6248528)